# When would I use twos, ones, or just signed?

Tags: numbers, twos-complement

If I want -3 in binary, I can use signed bit, or ones complement, or two's complement, correct?
However, when is it appropriate to use a method? and why?

Let's just use 8 bits:

`-3` with signed is just `10000011`

`-3` with ones is just `11111100`

`-3` with twos is just `11111101`

Comment: Compliments have nothing to do with it. Complements might, though.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm going to leave that uneditted for comedic reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia neatly summarizes the [benefits of two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

> The two's-complement system has the
>   advantage of not requiring that the
>   addition and subtraction circuitry
>   examine the signs of the operands to
>   determine whether to add or subtract.
>   This property makes the system both
>   simpler to implement and capable of
>   easily handling higher precision
>   arithmetic. Also, zero has only a
>   single representation, obviating the
>   subtleties associated with negative
>   zero, which exists in ones'-complement
>   systems.